# ManyToMany with more columns in the relational table

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008, jpa

I have this scenario:

**Table Group**
idgroup
groupname
...

**Table Interval**
idInterval
Description
...

**Table group_interval**
idInterval
idGroup
active

I had to change the relationship on JPA from `manyToMany` to `manyToOne` - `OneToMany`.
Everything works fine but when I need to insert I have some problems.

First, the exception was that query had `idinterval` occurred twice, so, couldn't set. 
Later, after some changes, I got the exception `... index 8 ...` out of bounds, and assume this was relate to setting extra parameters than allowed in the table.

I'm using a `mappedSupperClass` and extending to classes, and that's the reason I think these errors is relate to extra parameter in the query.

Here's my classes, insert method and stacktrace error.

***Base entity***

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

hashCode, equals and toString
```

***Interval***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TUnPbxPauseStatusType")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "IdStatusType", insertable = false, updatable = false))
public class Interval extends BaseEntity implements Serializable
...
private List<IntervalGroup> listIntervalGroup;
...

@Override
@Id
public Long getId()
{
    return super.getId();
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id)
{
    super.setId(id);
}

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "interval")
public List<IntervalGroup> getListIntervalGroup()
{
    return listIntervalGroup;
}

public void setListIntervalGroup(List<IntervalGroup> listIntervalGroup)
{
    this.listIntervalGroup = listIntervalGroup;
}
```

***Group***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TUnPbxGroup")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "GroupId", insertable = false, updatable = false))
public class MainGroup extends BaseEntity implements Serializable

...

private List<IntervalGroup> listIntervalGroup;

...

@Override
@Id
public Long getId()
{
    return super.getId();
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id)
{
    super.setId(id);
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainGroup")
public List<IntervalGroup> getListIntervalGroup()
{
    return listIntervalGroup;
}

public void setListIntervalGroup(List<IntervalGroup> listIntervalGroup)
{
    this.listIntervalGroup = listIntervalGroup;
}
```

***IntervalGroup***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TUnpbxPauseGroup")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "fkidstatustype", insertable = false, updatable = false))
@IdClass(IntervalGroup.class)
public class IntervalGroup extends BaseEntity implements Serializable

...

private MainGroup mainGroup;
private Interval interval;
private long idGroup;

    @Override
@Id
public Long getId()
{
    return super.getId();
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id)
{
    super.setId(id);
}

@Id
@Column(name = "fkidGroup", nullable = true)
public long getIdGroup()
{
    return idGroup;
}

public void setIdGroup(long idGroup)
{
    this.idGroup = idGroup;
}


@ManyToOne(targetEntity = MainGroup.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkIdGroup")
public MainGroup getMainGroup()
{
    return mainGroup;
}

public void setMainGroup(MainGroup mainGroup)
{
    this.mainGroup = mainGroup;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Interval.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "fkIdStatusType")
public Interval getInterval()
{
    return interval;
}

public void setInterval(Interval interval)
{
    this.interval = interval;
}
```

I tried override the `id` method from supperclass and used transient; Don't use `@AttributeOverride` in the `IntervalGroup` class (but i got that the name id doesn't exist);
I tried `@Embeddable` class, and a lot of another things. Nothing worked.

Maybe not using the `BaseEntity` class I would solve my problem, but I'd like to use this to use some generics methods.

Here's how I am trying to insert:

***IntervalController:***

```
for (IntervalGroup intervalGroups : getItem().getListIntervalGroup())
    {
        intervalService.save(intervalGroups); //Error happens here.
    }


save();//This saves the interval, after save intervalGroup
```

***GenericService***

```
public <T extends BaseEntity> T save(T entity)
{
    logger.info("Salvar: " + entity);

    if (entity.getId() == null)
    {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Remembering: Its search works perfectly, the problem happens only when I try to insert.

insert query:

```
(*fkidstatustype*, icActive, icBlockTime, *fkIdStatusType*, fkIdGroup, nuTime, nuTimeAfterUnlock) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

as shown, the fkidstatustype appears twice.

```
09:35:46,060 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
09:35:46,061 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) The index 8 is out of range.
09:35:46,062 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-5) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffac100058:7f5df46c:548ad301:27, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@1b90c55 >: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: The index 8 is out of range.
```

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem but according to the documentation the Inheritance annotation should be specified on the entity class that is the root of the entity class hierarchy. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html

Comment: And are you sure about your `insertable=false` ?